# How to update HAML so that link appears right after text

Tags: text, hyperlink, haml, html

I am using HAML to display my text as well as a link after it

```
.thread_text
  %a{href:"#"} <%= question.text %>
%span.remove_link
  %a{href: "#"} remove
```

The display is as such

[image]

However, what I really want is for the 'remove' link to appear right after the word 'recently'.

How can I modify the HAML to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
.thread_text
  %a{href:"#"} <%= question.text %>
  %span.remove_link
    %a{href: "#"} remove
```

Or better:

```
.thread_text
  %a(href="#")= question.text
  %span.remove_link
    %a(href="#") remove
```

It should work, if you have the correct css.
Also, you do not necessarily need the `span`: http://jsfiddle.net/DfBJv/2

Comment: I concur. For edification, I point out that the reason the remove link was on the next line was that `thread_text` is a `div`. Moving the remove link inside `thread_text` solves that, as would making `thread_text` an inline element like `span`.

Comment: @BuckDoyle, thank you for your comment. However, it seems to me that at the picture the div has a limited width, so it can not be used as an inline tag. Compare this http://jsfiddle.net/DfBJv/2/ and this http://jsfiddle.net/DfBJv/3/.